# How can I send the equivalent of this curl request via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, curl

I need to be able to send a request formatted as follows via ajax:

curl -i -H "Range: results=0-9" http://mydomain.com/kls/api/search?q=vancouver%20pets

The part I can't figure out how to mix in is the "Range: results=0-9" part. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you mention which technology are you using?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to avoid jquery or any third-party frameworks if I don't really need them, so pretty much straight js. The back end is java. The request returns an array of JSON objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a header (-H option), so you can use the `setRequestHeader` function of your xhr object (jquery or not, it's the same object).

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Range', 'results=0-9');
```

Comment: This did it. Thanks! I'll add that these needs to be added after the request has been opened.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i can understand, you want to send some information as part of header
this link might be helpful
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/2918/how-to-set-a-request-header-in-a-jquery-ajax-call.aspx